# CSS element transition

Tags: css, transition

I have tried this construction in several browsers, and it not working. Please help to find my mistake.

```
<style>
.result{            
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #ff0000;
}           
.result #add{
    display:none;
}
.result:hover #add{
     -webkit-transition: top 1s ease-out 1.5s;
     -moz-transition: top 1s ease-out 1.5s;
     transition: top 1s ease-out 1.5s;
     display:block;
}
</style>

<div class="result">
    <div id="add">111</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: could you explain the transition you want to achieve please

Comment: `Display` property can't be animated with `transition` instead you can use `opacity`.

Comment: I'm going to add this as a comment, as most answers seem to miss this: you need to move your transitions to the **initial** state, or you will not experience a smooth transition once you are no longer hovering over the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A few things to clean up first**

1. You can't transition from `display: none` to `display: block`.  Just can't happen.  I would recommend transitioning `opacity: 0` to `opacity: 1` instead for a fade-in effect
2. Your `transition: top 1s ease-out 1.5s` call will *only animate top attribute*. That's what the `top` means in that line.  You can add multiple targets via a comma delimited list, e.g. `top 1s ease-out, opacity 1s ease-out` etc. etc.  Alternatively, you can just write the rule as `transition: 1s ease-out` and it will animate all changes (but this may have some minor performance hits as opposed to selecting the attributes to animate).
3. When using CSS transitions **you must have an *initial* and a *destination* state or the animation won't work**.  An example in your code would be:

---

```
 .result{            
     width: 200px;
     height: 300px;
    top: 0;
    background: #ff0000;
}           
.result #add{
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.result:hover #add{
     -webkit-transition: 1s ease-out 1.5s;
     -moz-transition: 1s ease-out 1.5s;
     transition: 1s ease-out 1.5s;
     opacity: 1;
     top: 40px;
}
```

And that, as written, should work for you.

Comment: If you want the transition to fade back as well, you need to put the transition into the initial state, not the `hover` state. http://jsfiddle.net/disinfor/rca3qbyn/

Comment: You also need to add positioning of absolute to the `#add` or it won't respond to `top`. I updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/disinfor/rca3qbyn/1/ :)

Comment: Good catch, moved that from `.result` to `.result #add`

Comment: +1 Sorry for getting picky on your answer, but it was the most comprehensive for the initial list you gave and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @disinfor - Totally understandable and I appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

3 issues:

- you're passing the `top` property into your transition `top 1s ease-out 1.5s;`
  but there's no `top` to refer to.
- Also you're not setting a `position` property for your `#add` element
- `display:block;` will trigger a fast redraw which will prevent the right CSS's calculations needed to apply the top transition - try with `opacity` instead

Here's all applied to an example:

```css
.result{            
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #ff0000;
}           
.result #add{
  opacity: 0;
  position:relative;
  top:0;
}
.result:hover #add{
  opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transition: top 1s ease-out 1.5s;
      -moz-transition: top 1s ease-out 1.5s;
           transition: top 1s ease-out 1.5s;
  top:150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="result">
    <div id="add">111</div>  
</div>
```